# Swift 5: Stuck on the searchTextField. Trying to do a search of city, state, and country

Tags: json, swift, api, url, textfield

The part I'm stuck on is when I enter city name, state name, and country name in the search bar, it doesn't update the city label, state label, nor country label.

Here is the following code for the searchPressed:

```
extension AirQualityViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBAction func searchPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(searchTextField.text!)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchTextField.endEditing(true)
    print(searchTextField.text!)
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.text != "" {
        return true
    } else {
        textField.placeholder = "Type something"
        return false
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let city = searchTextField.text, let state = searchTextField.text, let country = searchTextField.text {
        airQualityManager.fetchAirQuality(cityName: city, stateName: state, countryName: country)
    }
    searchTextField.text = ""
}
```

}

Here is how I call the fetch the air quality:

```
func fetchAirQuality(cityName: String, stateName: String, countryName: String) {
    let urlString = "\(cityURL)city=\(cityName)&state=\(stateName)&country=\(countryName)&key=\(apiKey)"
    performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    
}

func fetchAirQuality(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let urlString = "\(nearCityURL)lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&key=\(apiKey)"
    performRequest(urlString: urlString)
}
```

In the func textFieldDidEndEditing, is there another way to get separate textFields for the city name, state name, and country name?

Comment: Aren't you only using one textfield? Do you want 3 separate textfields, or just 1 where you input 3 terms?

Comment: @aheze Just 1 where we input 3 terms. I'm trying to figure out how to get to separate by characters like this ", "

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an array of each element, and you can access them directly by index.

`let array = str.components(separatedBy: ",")`